# Creating a tax computing program on c++ , error with uninitialized local variables

Tags: c++

First time posting here. Recently started a C++ class and I'm really enjoying it! I'm creating a tax computing program but ran into a bit of wall on this part. I don't know how its not initialized if I already stated it using 'double'
The variable that I'm having trouble with is "taxes2" on line 129
Please help if you can!

Also, this is the prompt im working with:
"Write a program to compute income tax as follows:

First, read the income for the year. Then, display the following menu and ask the user to select his or her filing status:

1. Single
2. Married filing separately
3. Married filing jointly
4. Head of household

For Single status, apply a deduction of $2000, for #2 $1700, for #3, $2300 and Head of household $2700.  Also, ask for and read the number of dependents. Add to the deduction amount, $150 for each dependent up to a maximum of 3 dependents if single, add $125 for each dependent up to a maximum of 4 for Married filing separately, and $175 for each dependent, up to a maximum of 5, if married filing jointly or head of household.

Then, compute the taxable income by subtracting the total deduction computed above from his or her income.  Anyone with a taxable income of less than $8,000 pays no taxes.  For the rest, the first $15,000 of the income has a tax rate of 10%, the next $25,000 gets taxed at 15%, the next $30,000 at 20%, the next $30,000 at 25% and anything above $100,000 at 30%.  So, for example, someone who had taxable income of $125,000, her first $15,000 gets taxed at 10% ($1,500), plus 15% of $25,000 ($3,750), plus 20% of $30,000 ($6,000), plus 25% of $30,000 ($7,500) and the remaining $25,000 at 30% ($7,500) for a total tax amount of $26,250.  For someone with income of $13,000, the tax is 10% of that or $1,300.  For someone who made $7,999.99 it would be 0, but for someone who made $8,000, it's $800.  For someone who made $30,000, it would be 10% of $15,000 or $1,500 plus 15% of the remaining $15,000 or $2,250 making it $3,750, and so on. Display the amount of taxes to be paid."

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
const double tax1 = 1500.00;
const double tax2 = 3750.00;
const double tax3 = 6000.00;
const double tax4 = 7500.00;

double income;
double istatus;
double itaxes;
double itaxes2;
double ideduction1;
double ideduction2;
double idependant;
const double idependantrate1 = 150;
const double idependantrate2 = 125;
const double idependantrate3 = 175;
double idependanttotal;



cout << "What is your income? " << endl;
cin >> income;

cout << "Please enter your filing status: \n";
cout << "1. Single \n";
cout << "2. Married Filing Separately \n";
cout << "3. Married Filing Jointly \n";
cout << "4. Head of Household \n";
cin >> istatus;


// Begin Deductions

if (istatus == 1)
{
    cout << "You've selected Single";
    ideduction1 = 2000;
    cout << "Please select number of dependants (max: 3): ";
    cin >> idependant;

    if (idependant >= 0)
    {
        idependant * idependantrate1 == idependanttotal;
    }

    idependanttotal + ideduction1 == ideduction2;



}

else if (istatus == 2)
{
    cout << "You've selected Married Filing Separately";
    ideduction1 = 1700;
    cout << "Please select number of dependants (max: 4): ";
    cin >> idependant;

    if (idependant >= 0)
    {
        idependant * idependantrate2 == idependanttotal;
    }

    idependanttotal + ideduction1 == ideduction2;



}


else if (istatus == 3)
{
    cout << "You've selected Married Jointly";
    ideduction1 = 2300;
    cout << "Please select number of dependants (max: 5): ";
    cin >> idependant;

    if (idependant >= 0)
    {
        idependant * idependantrate3 == idependanttotal;
    }

    idependanttotal + ideduction1 == ideduction2;



}

else if (istatus == 4)
{
    cout << "You've selected Head of Household";
    ideduction1 = 2700;
    cout << "Please select number of dependants (max: 5): ";
    cin >> idependant;

    if (idependant >= 0)
    {
        idependant * idependantrate3 == idependanttotal;
    }

    idependanttotal + ideduction1 == ideduction2;


}





// Calculate Income Taxes

if (income <= 7999.99)
{
    cout << "No taxes need to be paid. " << endl;
    return 0;
}
else if (income >= 8000.00 && income <= 15000.00)
{
    itaxes = income * .10;       //calculates tax amount
    itaxes - ideduction2 == itaxes2;
    cout << "The amount owed in taxes is: $" << itaxes2 << endl;

}
else if (income >= 15000.01 && income <= 40000.00)
{
    itaxes = ((income - 15000) * .15) + tax1;       //calculates tax amount
    itaxes - ideduction2 == itaxes2;
    cout << "The amount owed in taxes is: $" << itaxes2 << endl;


}
else if (income >= 40000.01 && income <= 70000.00)
{
    itaxes = ((income - 40000) * .20) + tax1 + tax2;       //calculates tax amount
    itaxes - ideduction2 == itaxes2;
    cout << "The amount owed in taxes is: $" << itaxes2 << endl;

}
else if (income >= 70000.01 && income <= 100000.00)
{
    itaxes = ((income - 70000) * .25) + tax1 + tax2 + tax3;       //calculates tax amount
    itaxes - ideduction2 == itaxes2;
    cout << "The amount owed in taxes is: $" << itaxes2 << endl;


}
else if (income > 100000.01)
{
    itaxes = ((income - 100000) * .30) + tax1 + tax2 + tax3 + tax4;       //calculates tax amount
    itaxes - ideduction2 == itaxes2;
    cout << "The amount owed in taxes is: $" << itaxes2 << endl;


}
else
    cout << "You have entered an unuseable number. Please restart the program and enter a positive number " << endl;

return 0;
```

Comment: As for uninitialized variables, you define plenty of variables at the top of the `main` function, but don't initialize all. Are you sure you later initialize them/assign to them before you otherwise use them in any calculations? Do the compiler complain about uninitialized variables? Doesn't is tell you *which* variables are uninitialized?

Comment: Thanks Some programmer dude. Sorry I totally forgot to put where the exact issue is. Just made an edit to the question. I get an "uninitialized local variable 'taxes2' used" on line 129

Comment: If you search for `itaxes2`, the first mention after the definition is `itaxes - ideduction2 == itaxes2`. Which uses the `itaxes2` variable without initialization. And the whole expression itself makes no sense at all. It compares the result of `itaxes - ideduction2` with the (uninitialized) `itaxes2`, and throw away the boolean result. What is it supposed to do? Do you perhaps mean `itaxes2 = itaxes - ideduction2`?

Comment: THAT WAS IT! I had to go back and do the same for other variables, but it worked! I didn't realize that it made a difference which side of the "=" sign it was. You've been so helpful! Thank you so much Some programmer dude!

Comment: Now here's a couple of important lessons: The difference between `=` and `==`; Be careful when copy-pasting code; And don't have a lot of code that is the same for multiple branches (either use functions, or put all the common code after the `else`). And yes, the "direction" of many operators is very relevant. You don't expect e.g. `10 / 5` to be equal to `5 / 10`? Assignment assigns the result of the ***right*** hand side to the variable on the ***left***.

Answer (score 0):

`idependant * idependantrate1 == idependanttotal` will calculate the value of `idependant * idependantrate1`, and then check if it equals `idependanttotal`. If you want to store the calculated value in `idependanttotal` write `idependanttotal = idependant * idependantrate1;`.